# Adjust image width but keep the same height

Tags: css, image, html

Sorry if this has already been asked, but I wasn't sure of the correct wording, so I couldn't search it up. I have an image that is very large width-wise, and I want it to go off of the browser window when using a smaller resolution, and if you have a bigger resolution, it will show more of the image (width wise ONLY, height needs to remain the same), this way it won't matter what resolution you're browsing at, the image will still be the same height, so the page content will stay mostly the same. Just putting it in with img tags adjusts the whole picture to fit the browser window, changing the height in the process. Below is a very crude diagram of what I want to happen.

[image: Image Diagram]

Comment: Just mocked up something. Is this good for you? http://jsfiddle.net/T7tEM/

Comment: @adaam It looks like what I want, I'm going to adjust it onto my site and get back to you.

Comment: That solution does not keep aspect ration same. Is it really that you want? Check out my answer, simple and does the work.
http://jsfiddle.net/SVxJ4/1/

Answer (score 1):

The simple option is to add `overflow: hidden;` to the image container. E.g. http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/Etikh

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.wrap {width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; background: ##e7e7e7; padding: 20px;}
.container {overflow: hidden;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1024X600" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed !important;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:red;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.container img {
    height:inherit;
    width:100%;
}
```

The container is `fixed` and it is 100% width and height with its top, left, right, bottom values all set to zero pixels. The img in the container inherits the height set in the container block but the width is 100%. 
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1024X768">    
</div>
```

JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CVNf9/

Comment: I don't have much time at the moment, so I may have done something wrong, but I couldn't get it working. I'm working on this site: http://soto.novicode.com/. The main picture needs to stay a certain height, but in order to keep the correct ratio, I want it to be able to go off of the page (like in my diagram). Right now it just adjusts the height so the width fits the browser sides.

Comment: @Novicode Then just set the img `width` property to a fixed width i.e. `width:1000px;` rather than a percentage. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CVNf9/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
.image-mask {
  margin: 10px;
  border: dotted 2px red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-mask img {
  display: block;
  width:1024px;
  height:768px;
}

<div class="image-mask">
  <img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/yourimage.png">
</div>
```

If necessary set a max-width on .image-mask (say if it has an actual border you want to display or something) to prevent it getting larger than the image width, or set `margin: 0 auto` to center it, etc.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aj59Z/2/

Answer (score -1):

As simple as that:

```
img {
  width: 1000px; /* Width of your img */
  height: 600px; /* Height of your img */
}
```

And to avoid horizontal scroll bar, wrap your image with some element and set its **overflow** attribute to **hidden**, **width** to **100%**

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SVxJ4/1/